# Cron Job on Google App Engine to Speed up pages

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I want to schedule a cron job on Google App Engine to view my 5 main pages every 10 minutes or so to keep a current instance up and running and to increase page speed for users.  I understand all of the basic syntax for creating a cron job but I am curious what the python would look like for that.  Do I simply need to make 5 different cron jobs and have each one fetch a URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your specific question, such a cron.yaml could look like this:

```
cron:
- description: five minute run
  url: /refresh
  schedule: every 5 minutes
```

where /refresh is a handler you've written in your app that is then called even N minutes automatically.

E.G. myapplication.appspot.com/refresh

There's no need to refresh a specific page or more than one. Just having the handler called will keep your app alive.

But as others have noted, this is a bit much to keep an app permanently warm.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to resort to this. You can pay to have App Engine keep a certain number of frontends running constantly. They're referred to as "resident" instances.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances

Comment: I don't have many viewers and I would rather not pay but for the visitors that I do have I'd like the page to be fresh for them.  Do you think it would be effective at all?

Comment: You can use a cron job to ping your instance to keep it alive.  As long as your instance is alive, it should be serving quickly, and it will serve all 5 of your pages.  There's no point in hitting the 5 pages separately.

Comment: okay is there any advantage to doing my own cron job as opposed to a service like pingdom.com?

Comment: What is the difference between pinging to keep the instance alive vs. configuring an instance or two to stay alive? The resident instances feature was introduced so that people wouldn't have to ping to keep instances warm.

Comment: the difference for me is that one is free. unless I am mistaken and configuring it to always have one or two instances always alive is free as well

Comment: If you send a periodic request to keep your instance alive 24 hrs/day, you will only be within the free quota for instance hours for 4 more hours each day on a second instance -- so you'd have to be talking about a very low-traffic site, which may not be worth the effort of keeping warm using cron requests.

Comment: you are right Jason. Wich means that if you have a small app you can use this technique to keep alive and stay in the free quota but still have great responsivnes through the allways-on instance. But then you have to really care about design, because if you can get most of your http requests return under 100ms, if you use the threadsafe argument, if you supply a good parameter for the min req pending time, and use memcache everywhere, then your app will remain free for a very, very, very long time...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about AppEngine but, in generic Python, all you need is [urllib.urlopen()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).  I'd probably just have a single script that pulls all 5 pages in order - I can't really think of a reason to make them separate.

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling_min_instances

This seems like the proper way to solve the issue of your single low-traffic auto-scaled instance now. Basically just add this to your app.yaml:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1
```

...Then add the warmup handler to your app (just so you're not throwing a 400 error every time GAE attempts to warm up your app):
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests

Don't waste your time with pinging, this has the exact same effect & cost.

Answer (score -3):

Cron job can fetch only one url.

I see 2 way:
1. You can add cron for every page.
2. You can add one cron job and add [task](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) to each page from cron.

Comment: Cron job can do whatever you code it to do. It has more time allowed to executed (I believe 30 minutes) and easily urlfetch more than one URL (5 at once even!)